# Passing data from my MainDialog to Middlewares

Tags: c#, botframework

I am using the Virtual Assistant Template and using custom middelwares.

**what I want is to pass custom data in the activity Properties to my middleware from my MainDialog**

```cs
 turnContext.Activity.Properties["dummy"] = "data";
```

But the activity I receive in the middleware never has the Properties property set, it is always empty.

I know that:

> As each activity flows in and out of the bot, each piece of middleware can inspect or act upon the activity, both before and after the bot logic runs.

My case is needing to pass data to the middleware "after the bot logic runs" 
 How can I do that?

Comment: I think you need TurnState for this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54535119/getting-turnstate-data-from-dialogcontext

Comment: Thank you @Hessel for pointing me in the TurnState direction, that worked !

Comment: @Hessel - Would you like to post that as an answer or would you like Marc or me to do it? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: Whoever posts I will mark it as an answer, thank you again

Comment: @KyleDelaney.  Please do. I know  about TurnState but can't translate this into an answer that helps the community. An answer explaining how to actually use it would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn state is a [`TurnContextStateCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.turncontextstatecollection) which is a type that derives from `Dictionary<string, object>`. As such, you can use it like a dictionary. In the SDK, data is usually stored in turn state using `Add` because the SDK is written to only add the data once. If you try to use `Add` when the data is already present, it will throw an exception. If you want to ensure that data is present in the turn state and you don't know if it's already there or not, you can use `Set`. This is the same as using the indexer's set accessor:

```
turnContext.TurnState["dummy"] = "data";
```

You can access it from your middleware using `Get` or by using the indexer again:

```
var dummy = turnContext.TurnState["dummy"];
```

Note that the `TurnContextStateCollection` provides generic methods for convenience so that if you're only storing one object of a given type in your turn state then you don't need a key to get or set it. The key is generated automatically from the name of the type.

```
turnContext.TurnState.Set(new DummyData());

var dummy = turnContext.TurnState.Get<DummyData>();
```

Comment: Kyle, do you perhaps have a full sample using this? It looks like state management has changed somewhat, so I'd like to understand if there's an equivalent of SaveChangesAsync for state, for example

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow - Turn state isn't meant to be saved. Turn state only lasts for one turn. Use bot state for persistent state.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I think what's confusing me though is that on my adapter, I set "UseStorage" and "UseBotState", passing in User and Conversation state objects. The intellisense (i.e. the comments for) UseBotState say "The botstate will be available via the turn context's Microsoft.Bot.Builder.TurnContext.TurnState.TurnContextStateCollection". If "TurnState" is how I access these States, but "turn" state per se is only for "Turns", where/how do I actually put something in/read something out of, say, "User" state from within my bot?

Comment: Turn state is where bot state is cached. Bot state gets loaded into turn state from storage when it's first needed, and then saved from turn state back into the storage when you save the changes. This question/answer is about accessing turn state manually, and your issues surrounding UseStorage and UseBotState sound unrelated.

Comment: They are indeed unrelated at this point - could we continue this discussion somewhere you can suggest? A regular question will get flagged. SO Chat perhaps?

Comment: If you have a legitimate question, I don't know why it would get flagged. My recommendation is to have a look at the source code to see if that gives you any insight into how things work, and then post a question if you run into a point of difficulty.